# E-Mail Security thought certificate

Tags: certificate, linux, email, centos

Recently I have been trying to secure mail ports `993`/`995`/`465` with a certificate. It works when specifying the server hostname, But that's not an option on a shared server with numerous users.

The 'working' setup is:

```
            Protocol    domain/hostname     Port    SSL
Incoming    IMAP        shared.server.tld   993     SSL
Outgoing    SMTP        shared.server.tld   465     SSL
```

I need it to work for `mail.domainname`. So that the only thing the customers have to do is to turn on SSL in Apple Mail/OUTLOOK/Thunderbird, and or specify the 993/465 ports.

Right now when I specify the `mail.domainname` I get a certificate mismatch, because the cert is for `shared.server.tld` and not `mail.domainname`

How do I secure the mail.domainname ports with a certificate specified for `shared.server.tld`?

We have tried with a `srv` DNS record, and are looking to get this working with a autodiscover.

Answer (score 2):

Get a certificate with Subject Alternate Names for each of the hostnames involved - these are often sold as 'multi-domain' or 'multi-host' SSL certificates.

The hostname and a subject name MUST match, otherwise you are not protecting against MITM - after all, if they could differ, ANY certificate validly signed by a root CA would work for any host.

Comment: Not possible. We have way to many website running on our servers. We need to secure their e-mail traffic, not their website traffic. We have a wildcard certificate `*.shared.server.tld`? Others have got this working. Were the e-mail traffic is secured via SSL, and the websites have to be secured via a SSL certificate which they can purchase.

Comment: all other public providers use a shared domain, why can't you?

Comment: @JacobEvans Show me how they do it?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c

Comment: @blade19899 if you have a wildcard cert, it sounds like maybe it's not hooked up to your email servers, just the web-server (or vice versa).  I see this is an old post, but this is still a common issue, so putting my two cents in.  Be sure they are all using the same cert.  Just because they're running on the same physical or (or virtual) server OS doesn't mean they're connected to the same cert.

Answer (score 0):

Better, just get a cert from Lets Encrypt with whatever domains and subdomains you need (including mail.whatever-- and autodiscover.whatever though its not mandatory).  You'll have to renew every 90 days buts it's free, and better security to renew more often anyway, since you get a fresh cert.  There are ways of renewing automagically as well, so depending on your setup and needs it might be worth it.